# Should I use Stream API for simple iteration?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Are there any benefits in using the new Stream API for simple iterations?

Without Stream API:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        doSomething(entry);
    }
```

Using Stream API:

```
map.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
        doSomething(entry);
    });
```

Length and readability of code are about the same. Are there any important differences (e.g. in performance)?

Comment: Streams should be used if it can make your code shorter *and* more readable. So your use case there is not a good example by itself. However if you are going to use the `map.forEach` method itself, then there is some point in using lambdas, but then again, you're not using streams anymore at that point.

Comment: Same applies to the entrySet; you can say `map.entrySet().forEach(…)` without the need for a stream. In case of a single method invocation, the form `map.entrySet().forEach(context::doSomething);` is preferable to a lambda expression as it is *really* shorter and more readable. So if you have an *existing* method `doSomething` taking either a single entry instance or two parameters matching key and value, then there’s a point in using `forEach(…)`.

Comment: Also, even if you write it that way, you don't need the brackets in the second example. I think it's more readable that way...

Comment: Thanks guys, I learned something from all three comments. Netbeans highlighted the non-stream version and suggested a change. I hit enter and Netbeans then generated the stream version above...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Streams API makes parallelism much easier to accomplish (although you'll only see the benefit with a large sized collection). If you had to implement parallelism on your first example then there would be a sizeable difference in the amount of code (as opposed to adding .parallelStream() to the second example)

As per the [Java Trail on parallelism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html):

> One difficulty in implementing parallelism in applications that use
>   collections is that collections are not thread-safe, which means that
>   multiple threads cannot manipulate a collection without introducing
>   thread interference or memory consistency errors. The Collections
>   Framework provides synchronization wrappers, which add automatic
>   synchronization to an arbitrary collection, making it thread-safe.
>   However, synchronization introduces thread contention. You want to
>   avoid thread contention because it prevents threads from running in
>   parallel. Aggregate operations and parallel streams enable you to
>   implement parallelism with non-thread-safe collections provided that
>   you do not modify the collection while you are operating on it. Note
>   that parallelism is not automatically faster than performing
>   operations serially, although it can be if you have enough data and
>   processor cores. While aggregate operations enable you to more easily
>   implement parallelism, it is still your responsibility to determine if
>   your application is suitable for parallelism.

Answer (score 3):

You had asked about Streams, but as skiwi's comment noted, passing a lambda to the `forEach` default method on Map possibly fills the bill if the iteration is simple and doesn't require parallelism or any additional logic. Assuming that `doSomething` can be refactored to take separate key and value args instead of a `Map.Entry`, this can be reduced to a one-liner:

```
    map.forEach(MyClass::doSomething);  // if doSomething is a static method

    map.forEach(this::doSomething);     // if doSomething is an instance method
```